# Dodging-code uncertainty (Unity, no Unity physics)

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I want to implement dodging which is something like a dash in a direction. It works pretty simple - if you move in a direction and press the button the character dodges there. The velocity should not matter for this, so that the dodging speed is always the same, no matter if you are running or standing and then pressing a direction + dodging. I've got something that seems to work but there are still problems left. It seems like that diagonal dodging is a bit too far in comparison to horizontal/vertical dodging and I tried to fix this. But I'm still not sure if it worked or not. In practice the character dodges and stuff but something still seems off, like it works pretty good with a controller but sometimes it's still wacky when using keyboard after standing still and then using dodge. The thing is - I'm not sure if the code I have is the best I could have or if there are still problems.
A good example of how it should work would be the dodging in Rune Factory 4.
Edit: If the problem lies in the Input Settings I could show them.

```
        if (IsDodging == false)
          {
            Vector3 input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            if (input.sqrMagnitude > 1) input.Normalize();
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                // Jumping stuff I blended out
            }
            else if (Input.GetButtonDown("Block/Dodge") && input.x != 0 || Input.GetButtonDown("Block/Dodge") && input.z != 0) // To activate dodging
            {
                    if (Time.time > Time_Start + DodgeCooldown) // Checks the cooldown
                    {
                    Time_Start = Time.time;
                    IsDodging = true;
                    dodge_direction = input;
                    if (dodge_direction.x > 0) { dodge_direction.x = 1; } // To fixate the distance traveled when dodging while ignoring how fast you are
                    if (dodge_direction.z > 0) { dodge_direction.z = 1; }
                    if (dodge_direction.x > 0 && dodge_direction.z > 0) { dodge_direction.Normalize(); } // To prevent diagonal dodging distance from becoming too big
                    }
            }

            else
            {
                // Walk.
                transform.position += input * run_speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position += dodge_direction * dodge_distance;
            distance_traveled += Vector3.Distance(transform.position, dodge_direction * dodge_distance) * Time.deltaTime;
            if (distance_traveled > dodge_distance)
            {
                IsDodging = false;
                dodge_direction = Vector3.zero;
                distance_traveled = 0;
            }
        }
```